# Parallax page html and css

Tags: html, css, web

So I'm creating a parallax page and i did:

```
<section class="parallax">
 <div class="parallax-inner">
       <h2>Space</h2>
 </div>
```

On the css then I put a background and some padding. But here's the problem: I created an h1:

```
<section class="parallaxtop">
 <div class="parallax-inner-2">
     <h1>Space</h1>     
 </div>
```

And I set the background bbut it doesn't appear!! I'm 100% sure that i put the right file and the right directory! And I did the same with the h2 div! What should i do?

```
.parallaxtop{
   background: url("img/pattern.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full reproducible demo. Try to use color instead of image.

Comment: Here you are http://codepen.io/Boogieee/pen/WxvLVV

Answer (score 1):

**there's a typo** on `.parallaxtop`
you used `color('')` instead of `url('')`
should be:

```css
.parallaxtop{
    background: url("img/money.jpg"); 
}
```